# How to fix Boost::Asio Client Http request error?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to lean [Boost](https://www.boost.org/)::Asio networking library for C++ by watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hNdkYInj4g) but I stuck at making request using threads asynchronously.

The code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ts/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ts/internet.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

std::vector<char> vBuffrer(20 * 1024);

void GrabSomeData(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket) {

    socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(vBuffrer.data(), vBuffrer.size()),
        [&](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        //boost::system::error_code ec
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "\n\nRead" << length << "bytes\n\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                std::cout << vBuffrer[i];
            GrabSomeData(socket);
        }
    });


}

int main()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    boost::asio::io_context::work idleWork(context);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("13.107.21.200",ec),80);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);
    std::thread thrContext = std::thread([&]() {context.run(); });
    std::cout << "Starting " << std::endl;
    socket.connect(endpoint,ec);

    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected ! " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Fail to connect ! " << ec.message() << std::endl;

    }

    if (socket.is_open()) {

        GrabSomeData(socket);
        std::string sRequest =
            "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            "Host: www.example.com\r\n"
            "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(sRequest.data(), sRequest.size()), ec);

        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2800ms);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);

        context.stop();
        if (thrContext.joinable()) thrContext.join();
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Microsoft Visual studio give me this :

```
Error C2752 'asio_prefer_fn::call_traits<boost::asio::execution::any_executor<boost::asio::execution::context_as_t<boost::asio::execution_context &>,boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::never_t<0>,boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::possibly_t<0>>,boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::tracked_t<0>>,boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::untracked_t<0>>,boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::relationship::fork_t<0>>,boost::asio::execution::prefer_only<boost::asio::execution::detail::relationship::continuation_t<0>>> &,void (const boost::asio::execution::detail::blocking::possibly_t<0> &,boost::asio::execution::allocator_t<std::allocator<void>>),void>': more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list  boostasiotest   c:\boost\boost_1_75_0\boost\asio\detail\handler_work.hpp    353


Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<asio_prefer_fn::call_traits<T,void(P0,P1,PN...),void>::overload==,call_traits<T,void(P0,P1,PN...),void>::result_type>::type asio_prefer_fn::impl::operator ()(T &&,P0 &&,P1 &&,PN &&...) noexcept(<expr>) const'  boostasiotest   c:\boost\boost_1_75_0\boost\asio\detail\handler_work.hpp    353
```

Everything worked fine till I added **GrabSomeData** function and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it , any help would be appreciated.

**PS :** there is an example on the Boost website on this [subject](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp), but it is object oriented and all the pointers are referring to the class and I (think) it can't help.

Comment: does not compile "fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you compile it on Linux?

Comment: yes; please use standard headers

Comment: It is standard for Windows, stdafx.h is a Windows thing. it wouldn't compile on Visual Studio if I delete it from headers. not that I like it to be on Windows but the tutorial is that way, and the Boost is suppose to be cross platform!

Comment: well seems awkward, there is nothing specific to window in your code as far a I see... (except `pause` command )

Comment: FYI, compiles/links/runs fine here (without stdafx.h, obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sehe for the answer and recommendations, it took so long but I've upgrade to New **Windows10** and **Visual Studio 2019**, and **Boost 1_76** and the problem solved!

Those errors were totally irrelevant to the code!

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenter, I cannot repro your message: it just compiles,

- MSVC 19, /std:c++14, Boost 1.75.0: [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/fz1fhfc39)

Now, I **do** see other issues:

1. `write_some` may not write all the data - you will want to ensure a composed-write operation
2. a race condition: since you're doing `GrabSomeData` on a thread, you
   need to synchronize access to the `tcp::socket` and `buffer` (the
   shared resources).

   > `io_context` itself is thread-safe.

   In this case, it's really easy to avoid, since you don't need to
   start the async operation until after you sent the request:

   ```
   write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(sRequest));
   GrabSomeData(socket);
   ```
3. `async_read_some` has a similar problem as the write side. You will want a composed read operation that reads the expected output so `read_until(socket, buf, "\r\n\r\n")` and then read how much content is expected based on `Content-Length` header, `Connection: Close` and others (think chunked encoding).

   You currently have no good way to store and access the response. It would be a lot easier to use a streambuf, a single composed read.

   If you want to be really solid, use Beast to receive a HTTP/1.1 response (which can even be chunked) and not worry about when it's complete (the library does it for you):

   ```
   auto GrabSomeData(tcp::socket& socket) {
       http::response<http::string_body> res;

       auto buf = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(vBuffer);
       http::read(socket, buf, res);

       return res;
   }
   ```

   Oh, and don't do it on a thread (why was that anyways? it literally just introduced undefined behavior for no gain):

### Simplified Code

**[Live On Coliru](https://godbolt.org/z/jMrYhde8h)**

**[Compiles on MSVC: Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jMrYhde8h)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::vector<char> vBuffer; // TODO FIXME global variable

auto GrabSomeData(tcp::socket& socket) {
    namespace http = boost::beast::http;

    http::response<http::string_body> res;

    auto buf = boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(vBuffer);
    http::read(socket, buf, res);

    return res;
}

int main() try {
    boost::asio::io_context context;

    std::cout << "Starting " << std::endl;
    tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address("13.107.21.200"), 80);
    tcp::socket   socket(context);
    socket.connect(endpoint);

    std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl;

    std::string const sRequest = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: www.example.com\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "\r\n";

    write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(sRequest));

    auto response = GrabSomeData(socket);

    std::cout << "Response body length: " << response.body().size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response headers: " << response.base() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response body: " << std::quoted(response.body()) << std::endl;

    context.run(); // run_for(10s) e.g.
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    std::cerr << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
}
```

This sample printed:

```
Starting 
Connected
Response body length: 194
Response headers: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-MSEdge-Ref: 0BstXYAAAAACeQ2y+botzQISiBe2U3iGCQ0hHRURHRTE0MDgARWRnZQ==
Date: Sun, 21 Mar 2021 22:39:02 GMT
Connection: close

Response body: "<h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p>0BstXYAAAAACeQ2y+botzQISiBe2U3iGCQ0hHRURHRTE0MDgARWRnZQ=="
```

> **NOTE** It does indeed use chunked encoding, which you didn't seem to be anticipating.